# Unique NSManagedObject Attribute

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

What's the best way to make an `NSManagedObject` attribute Unique?

For example, should `willSave` or `validateForInsert:` or `validateForUpdate:` managed object methods be used to check if the value entered in `attributeUnique` is Unique? And, how exactly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253378/coredata-unique-objects-by-attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing an `NSManagedObject` category method, and using the `NSManagedObject`'s validation method:

```
- (BOOL)isValueUniqueForKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:[self.entity name]
                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    id value = [self valueForKey:key];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ = %@", key, value];
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSUInteger count = [self.managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                 error:&error];

    if (count > 1) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Your prescription is incomplete - you just wrote a basic code that verifies that some attribute value does not occurs twice or more in the object graph.

Comment: Your prescription is incomplete - isValueUniqueForKey: merely verifies attribute value does not occurs twice or more in the object graph. You did NOT tell what NSMnaagedOBject's validation method you used. Was it validateForInsert:? validatForUpdate: validate<key>:error:? I have tried this in the validate<key>:error: method, and it does not work, because at the time the user types in a value, the count is still 1, as change wasn't yet set to the attribute. This check is "post mortem". It tells you your database is invalid already. I would like to prevent this from happening on the first place.